# Creating a BufferedImage from .tiff file

Tags: java, bufferedimage

I'm trying to created a BufferedImage from a .tiff file (raw() is the path of a .tiff image):

```
// read a buffered image from the disk
BufferedImage buff = ImageIO.read(new File(raw()));
```

Originally ImageIO.read was returning null but I read that I need to add the JAI ImageIO JARs to your classpath, which I did. Now I'm getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.imageio.IIOException: I/O error reading image metadata!
        at com.sun.media.imageioimpl.plugins.tiff.TIFFImageReader.readMetadata(TIFFImageReader.java:340)
        at com.sun.media.imageioimpl.plugins.tiff.TIFFImageReader.seekToImage(TIFFImageReader.java:310)
        at com.sun.media.imageioimpl.plugins.tiff.TIFFImageReader.prepareRead(TIFFImageReader.java:971)
        at com.sun.media.imageioimpl.plugins.tiff.TIFFImageReader.read(TIFFImageReader.java:1153)
        at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1422)
        at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1282)
        at core.Page.initGuesses(Page.java:101)
....
```

Does anyone know what could be the problem? Am I doing something incorrectly?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try the ImageIO.getImageReadersByFormatName("tiff"); method to see if it returned something? If so, what does it return? This should tell you if your particular platform/environment claims to have a decoder for .tiff, or any other arbitrary format.

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing same problem. I was trying to get BufferedImage from tiff byte[] but was getting null as result.

I have commented one line from Tomcat's server.xml file which is related to JreMemoryLeaks.
Just comment this line:

```
Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener"
```

This solution worked for me.